# Performance: get+[delete if exists] vs delete

Tags: tarantool

I have a case with two options:

1. check a tuple existense and delete if it exists
2. unconditional delete

The majority of operations are trying to delete a tuple which is not exist in space (get without delete or uncoditional delete).

I wonder what is preferrable operation?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR: option 1 will be usually faster.**

In general, `DELETE` operation is slower then get, since it's write operation. 
However, there are several moments that may change this on your particular workload:

1. `DELETE` operation on a non-existent key will still generate a wal-entry, which will take most of it's time. So, if you use `wal_mode='none'`, no-op `DELETE` will be much faster.
2. `GET` operation will lead to msgpack decoding, so if your keys are relatively small, and tuples are relatively large, your `GET` operations will be slower.
3. (Obviously) percentage of non-existent keys in your requests will affect speed ratio between two options significantly.

You may tune this short bench to see real numbers:

```lua
clock = require('clock')
box.cfg{}
t = box.schema.space.create('t', {if_not_exists=true})
t:create_index('pk', {if_not_exists=true})
t:truncate()
for i = 1,10000 do
    t:replace{i, 'abcdef'}
end

local keys = {}
for i=1,50000 do
    table.insert(keys, math.random(1, 50000))
end

tm = clock.time()
for _, key in ipairs(keys) do
    --if t:get(key) ~= nil then
        t:delete(key)
    --end
end
collectgarbage()
print(clock.time()-tm)
```

Here,

- numbers are used in keys,
- short strings are used as tuple payload,
- and  get-hit ratio is approximately 20%.

Uncomment the if-clause to measure option 1.

On my laptop and numbers above, this bench shows that option 1 is roughly 6 times faster.

Comment: `clock.time` is not appropriate for benchmarks. Use `clock.proc`. (It doesn't change the overall conclusion on the point though.)